# Dell XPS13 -- Kernel Panic on Suspend

Tags: 15.04

I've been having an issue every so often where if I suspend the laptop by closing the lid, it seems to go into a kernel panic and the caps lock key blinks, resulting in having to manually restarting it. I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with the latest kernel as well. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Any suggestions I could try to resolve it?

Thanks guys!

Comment: what does the following command return? `sudo pm-is-supported --suspend-hybrid && echo "hybrid suspend is supported" || echo "your system doesn't support hybrid suspend"`

Comment: Hi mchid, the output of the above command displays: hybrid suspend is supported.

Comment: how much ram do you have and how big is your swap partition?

Comment: I have about 4GB of RAM, and my swap is roughly 4GB as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sputnik kernel solved the suspend issues I was having:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/sputnik-kernel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the Broadcom firmware when the Wifi card changes the status of the network. Canonical published a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~inaddy/+archive/ubuntu/lp1415880) including a patched version of `bcmwl` package to correct this problem.

Install it by running :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:inaddy/lp1415880
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

Refer to this [Barton George's blog post](http://bartongeorge.net/2015/09/01/kernel-panics-when-switching-wireless-networks-xps-13-developer-edition-9343/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new bios A05 version out, available on dell support website. This helped me with some issues.